# List the details of emp ,department SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Here I have 2 tables, Employee and Department, and the data as follows.

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

The required output is

- Display the list of departments and the number of employees employed in them
- View employees earning the most in individual departments

Comment: Do you want this all in one SQL statement?

Comment: Have you tried it by yourself first?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simple do `JOIN` with aggregation :

```
SELECT d.dname, COUNT(e.empno) as no_employees, max(e.sal) as most_sal
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN
     Department d
     ON d.deptno = e.deptno 
GROUP BY d.dname;
```

Comment: Thanks your answer helped to understand a little sql.